# Linux at command with seconds precision

Tags: linux, at

I'm looking for some Linux command which may launch another command at a specific time.

I know about the `at` command, but it gives me only minutes precision, and I need seconds precision. Is there an option with at command that I'm not aware of? Or is there any other command I should use?

Any orientation will be useful.

Comment: Why? If a scheduler checked every second then it would eat up tons of processor. Why isn't minute precision good enough?

Comment: You'll have to suffer with a little lack of precision - my results to `time sleep 5` give me an extra `.003` seconds. Try that command on your machine to see how accurate it will be.

Comment: @tjameson , because I need to schedule something for 5 seconds or so, and the at command doesn't works for me. I wasn't going for the sleep command, but I guess I'll have to do with it. Thanks

Comment: @beatgammit There are plenty of applications where second-level precision may be relevant.  See [real-time computing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real-time_computing) for some examples.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/9619362/974555

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `cron` to run a script that calls the [sleep](http://linux.die.net/man/3/sleep) command for the sub-miniute precision bit of it? So

```
sleep 10 ; foo.sh
```

should run `foo.sh` 10 seconds after the command is called.

Comment: Do you know anything about its precision? Or the precision of `at` in executing something at exactly `xx:xx:00:000`? If the user requires this kind of precision, it's conceivable that `at` and `sleep` won't cut it.

Comment: sleep on ubuntu and as such debian accepts floating point values. "Unlike most  implemenatations  that require NUMBER be an integer, here NUMBER may be an arbitrary floating point number."  However, if he needs smaller than whatever precision float supports... i have no clue

Comment: I meant more along the lines of whether his script actually will start exactly at `:10` when he specifies `sleep 10`, or maybe more like `:11` or `:12`...

Comment: no idea, actually. i've mostly seen wait used as a 'lets give things a while to settle down' way, rather than as a precision timing instrument.

Comment: Bog standard linux is not a real time system and offers *no* absolute timing guarantees. Get it heavily loaded and thrashing and things can become very delayed, indeed. *// too much experience with systems that have **nearly** enough memory*

Answer (score 0):

You can schedule your job at the nearest minute, then use [`alarm`](https://manpages.debian.org/bullseye/manpages-dev/alarm.2.en.html) to get second-level precision.  For an example in Python:

```
from signal import signal, setitimer, ITIMER_REAL, SIGALRM, alarm
from datetime import datetime, time
from sys import argv, exit
from time import sleep

at = datetime.combine(datetime.now(), time.fromisoformat(argv[1]))

class Done(Exception):
    pass

def _handler(signum, frame):
    print("The time is", datetime.now())
    raise Done()

setitimer(ITIMER_REAL, (at - datetime.now()).total_seconds())
signal(SIGALRM, _handler)

try:
    while True:
        sleep(1)
except Done:
    pass
```

Running:

```
$ python at-second.py 13:36:28
The time is 2022-07-06 13:36:28.000238
```

A limitation for this method:

> only one alarm can be scheduled at any time

So if you need multiple events in a minute, you'd need to schedule the second one only after the first one is finished.